# php - get full image path from server

Tags: php, image, path

how can i get image path on server using "browse" button in a html form, select the file (double clicking the file returning its full path), and put the result image path into variable $img_path?

let's say the image dir in my server is /images, i'd like to get path of "foo.jpg", the full image path should be "/images/foo.jpg"

so, all i have to do is :
1. create form which contain "browse" button or something like that - that allow me to explore "images" directory at my server
2. exploring "images" dir, all files listed and clickable, locate "foo.jpg", select it, and voila, i get the image path "/images/foo.jpg"

any lil' help would be appreciated..
Thanks

---

@CodeCaster thanks for your respond.. but this is all i want (at least closer) :

```
<?php

$dir = '/images';
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ($dp = opendir($dir)) {
        $files = array();
        while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) {
            if (!is_dir($dir . $file)) {
                $files[] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($dp);
    } else {
        exit('Directory not opened.');
    }
    if ($files) {
        echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            echo '<input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="' . $file . '" /> ' .
                 $file . '<br />';
        }
        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />' .
             '</form>';
    } else {
        exit('No files found.');
    }
} else {
    if (isset($_POST['files'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['files'] as $value) {
            echo $dir . $value . '<br />';
        }
    } else {
        exit('No files selected');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "browse button" - you mean an `<input type"'file'>`? Those can't be used to browse files on the server

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dir`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dir.php):

```
echo "<ul>";

$d = dir("images");
echo "Handle: " . $d->handle . "\n";
echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo "<li><a href=\"/images/" . $entry . "\">" . $entry . "</a></li>";
}
$d->close();

echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

using "dir"  you can achieve your goal.

```
<?php
 $d = dir("/etc/php5");
 echo "Handle: " . $d->handle . "\n";
 echo "Path: " . $d->path . "\n";
 while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
   echo $entry."\n";
 }
 $d->close();
?>
```

Comment: with your code (and @CodeCaster) i only can list the file, i want the file listed are clickable and return the full image path

Comment: Well if you have full path and if you don't have any access constrains on that folder then you can definitely use <a> tag and open file on mouse click